# A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

**UserProfileModel has two embedded models. I am giving here concisely:**

```
@Document(collection = "USER_PROFILE")
public class UserProfileModel extends BaseModel<UserModel>  {

    public static final String FIELD_USER_ID = "userId";
    public static final String FIELD_BASIC_INFO = "basicInfo";
    public static final String FIELD_CONTACT_INFO = "contactInfo";

    private String userId;
    private BasicInfo basicInfo;
    private ContactInfo contactInfo;
}

public class BasicInfo {
    private String gender;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String[] langs;
    private String religiousView;
    private String politicalView;
}

public class ContactInfo {
    private String[] mobilePhones;
    private Address address;
    private SocialLink[] socialLinks;
    private String[] websites;
    private String[] emails;
}
```

**Writing converter class of UserProfileModel:**

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
public class UserProfileModelConverter implements Converter<UserProfileModel, Document> {

    @Override
    public Document convert(UserProfileModel s) {
        Document doc = new Document();

        if (null != s.getUserId())
            doc.put(UserProfileModel.FIELD_USER_ID, s.getUserId());

        if (null != s.getBasicInfo())
            doc.put(UserProfileModel.FIELD_BASIC_INFO, s.getBasicInfo());

        if (null != s.getContactInfo())
            doc.put(UserProfileModel.FIELD_CONTACT_INFO, s.getContactInfo());
    }
}
```

**Trying to save an object of UserProfileModel like this:**

```
@Autowired
private UserProfileRepository repo;

UserProfileModel profileModel = generateUserProfileModel();
repo.save(profileModel);
```

**Exception:**

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when encoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Encoding a BasicInfo: 'BasicInfo(gender=Male, birthDate=2020-05-05, langs=[Lang 1, Lang 2], religiousView=Islam (Sunni), politicalView=N/A)' failed with the following exception:

Failed to encode 'BasicInfo'. Encoding 'langs' errored with: Can't find a codec for class [Ljava.lang.String;.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.

    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.encode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:53)
    at org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext.encodeWithChildContext(EncoderContext.java:91)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:185)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:199)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:141)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
```

---

If I don't use converter for `UserProfileModel` by adding in Mongo Config, then this exception doesn't appear and everything works well.

But I am trying to use the Converter class for some reason.

So is it something wrong or modification needed in converter class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Jira ticket already raised on this issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1894).

> Can't find a codec for class [Ljava.lang.String;

And their reply

> The Document class currently supports only List, not native Java
>   array, so just replace with:
>
> List codes = Arrays.asList("1112233", "2223344");

So, String array is not supported. Use `List<String>` instead of `String[]` in models.

Comment: Yes. right you are. I found it myself after posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this issue:

1. Either change `String[]` to `List<String>` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62290002/2987755)
2. Write your custom codec (if you do not have control over a class)

Following is solution 2:

1. Create a custom Code `StringArrayCodec`
2. Register it along with the existing codec
3. Start/restart application which uses mongo-java driver

Following is Kotlin code but can be converted to java as well.

1. **StringArrayCodec.kt**

```kotlin
import java.util.*
import org.bson.BsonReader
import org.bson.BsonType
import org.bson.BsonWriter
import org.bson.codecs.Codec
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext

class StringArrayCodec : Codec<Array<String>> {

    /**
     * Encode an instance of the type parameter `T` into a BSON value.
     * @param writer the BSON writer to encode into
     * @param value the value to encode
     * @param encoderContext the encoder context
     */
    override fun encode(writer: BsonWriter?, value: Array<String>?, encoderContext: EncoderContext?) {
        writer?.writeStartArray()
        val isNonNull = value != null
        if (isNonNull) {
            writer?.writeBoolean(isNonNull)
            value?.size?.let { writer?.writeInt32(it) }
            for (i in value!!) {
                writeValue(writer, i, encoderContext)
            }
        } else {
            writer?.writeBoolean(!isNonNull)
        }
        writer?.writeEndArray()
    }

    private fun writeValue(writer: BsonWriter?, s: String, encoderContext: EncoderContext?) {
        if (s == null) {
            writer?.writeNull()
        } else {
            writer?.writeString(s)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Class instance that this encodes. This is necessary because Java does not reify generic types.
     *
     * @return the Class instance that this encodes.
     */
    override fun getEncoderClass(): Class<Array<String>>? {
        return Array<String>::class.java
    }

    /**
     * Decodes a BSON value from the given reader into an instance of the type parameter `T`.
     *
     * @param reader         the BSON reader
     * @param decoderContext the decoder context
     * @return an instance of the type parameter `T`.
     */
    override fun decode(reader: BsonReader?, decoderContext: DecoderContext?): Array<String>? {
        reader?.readStartArray()
        val isNonNull = reader?.readBoolean()
        val tempArray: Array<String?>?
        if (isNonNull == true) {
            val size = reader.readInt32()
            tempArray = arrayOfNulls(size)
            for (i in 0 until size) {
                tempArray[i] = readValue(reader, decoderContext)
            }
        } else {
            tempArray = null
        }
        val array: Array<String>? = if (isNonNull == true) {
            Arrays.stream(tempArray)
                .filter { s ->
                    s != null
                }
                .toArray() as Array<String>
        } else {
            null
        }
        reader?.readEndArray()
        return array
    }

    private fun readValue(reader: BsonReader, decoderContext: DecoderContext?): String? {
        val bsonType: BsonType = reader.currentBsonType
        return if (bsonType == BsonType.NULL) {
            reader.readNull()
            null
        } else {
            reader.readString()
        }
    }
}
```

2. Register custom codec as **`CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(StringArrayCodec())`**

**MongodbConfig.kt**

```kotlin
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase
import org.bson.Document
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component


@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongodb")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["mongodb.enable"], havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
@Component
class MongodbConfig
    (
    @Value("\${mongodb.uri}")
    val connectionUri: String,

    @Value("\${mongodb.database}")
    val database: String,

    @Value("\${mongodb.collection-name}")
    val collectionName: String
) {

    @Bean
    fun mongoClient(): MongoClient {
        return MongoClients.create(mongodbSettings())
    }

    @Bean
    fun mongoDatabase(mongoClient: MongoClient): MongoDatabase {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase(database)
    }

    @Bean
    fun mongodbCollection(mongoDatabase: MongoDatabase): MongoCollection<Document> {
        return mongoDatabase.getCollection(collectionName)
    }

    fun mongodbSettings(): MongoClientSettings {
        val pojoCodecRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromRegistries(
            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(StringArrayCodec()), // <---- this is the custom codec
            MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
            fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build())
        )

        val connectionString = ConnectionString(connectionUri)
        return MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .build()
    }
}
```

3. Dependency and driver version

```kotlin
implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.2.0") {
    because("To connect mongodb instance")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from dkb re StringArrayCodec was helpful to me.
If you wish to avoid kotlin and use java instead then here is a non-kotlin-spam-java version:

```
import org.bson.BsonReader;
import org.bson.BsonWriter;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;

public final class MongoCodecStringArray implements Codec {

  public void encode(BsonWriter writer, String[] value, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
    if (writer == null)
        return;

    writer.writeStartArray();
    boolean isNonNull = value != null;
    writer.writeBoolean(isNonNull);
    if (isNonNull) {
        writer.writeInt32(value.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
            writer.writeString(value[i]);
        }
    }
    writer.writeEndArray();
}

public void encode(BsonWriter var1, Object var2, EncoderContext var3) {
    this.encode(var1, (String[]) var2, var3);
}

public Class getEncoderClass() {
    return String[].class;
}

public String[] decodeImpl(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
    if (reader == null)
        return null;

    reader.readStartArray();
    Boolean isNonNull = reader.readBoolean();
    String[] ret = null;
    if (isNonNull) {
        int size = reader.readInt32();
        ret = new String[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            ret[i] = reader.readString();
        }
    }
    reader.readEndArray();

    return ret;
}

public Object decode(BsonReader var1, DecoderContext var2) {
    return decodeImpl(var1, var2);
}
}
```

.